# Handle simultaneous get calls in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

My angular application is divided into 4 modules and all modules require user details so I am calling getUser method from each of the module. So when my application loads all 4 modules hit the getUser API simultaneously resulting in 4 get requests on server. How can I prevent this ? I am using singleton pattern in my getUser method so once my user gets loaded it will simply serve the user from an object. But that does not solves the problem if all modules request for the user simultaneously.

My code looks like this

```
getUser() {
let defer = this.q.defer();

if (!this.user) {
    this.http.get(`${this.config.apiHost}users`)
        .success(result => {
            this.user = result;

            this.rootScope.$broadcast('userFound', this.user);
            defer.resolve(this.user);
        })
        .error(err => defer.reject(err))
}
else {
    defer.resolve(this.user);
    this.rootScope.$broadcast('userFound', this.user);
}
return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: Add the call inside a service. The service will check if the user object exists. If it is the case, it returns the object - If not, return the get call. **OR** you can cache the call

Comment: I already have the method defined in the service only and it checks if the user object exists or not. But when all modules try to get the user simultaneously then this approach does not works.

Comment: do you use ui-router? .. i can suggest to you to use a resolve method in the routing and pass the result of the request to yours controller ..

Comment: What do you mean by module ? Multiple parts of the same page ? If it is the case why don't you load once when landing on the page ?

Comment: I am using stateProvider for routing

Comment: Module means: left bar, header, body. components on the page

Answer (score 1):

By storing the current request in a variable the call to `UserService.get` will return the same request promise.

Then when the promise resolves, it will resolve to all your modules.

```
    angular.module('app').service('UserService', function ($http) {

    var self = this;

    var getRequestCache;

    /**
     * Will get the current logged in user
     * @return user
     */
    this.get = function () {
        if (getRequestCache) {
            return getRequestCache;
        }

        getRequestCache = $http({
            url: '/api/user',
            method: 'GET',
            cache: false
        }).then(function (response) {
            // clear request cache when request is done so that a new request can be called next time
            getRequestCache = undefined;
            return response.data;
        });

        return getRequestCache;
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ui-router` for the routing. You can then use this to resolve the user when landing on the page.

In your routing config :

```
$stateProvider
    .state('myPage', {
        url: '/myPage',
        templateUrl: 'myPage.html',
        controller: 'myCtrl',
        resolve: {
            userDetails: ['UserService', function(UserService) {
                return UserService.getUserDetails();
            }],
        }
    })
```

In your controller

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .controller('myCtrl', ['userDetails', function(userDetails) {
        console.log(userDetails);
        }];
```

This will load the user details while loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using defer object as a global object so that it only gets initialised once.